# How to Implement AntiCSRF Token in Spring MVC(3.2.5) Project [EDITED]

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf, csrf-protection

I **Upgraded** from Spring 3.0.6 to 3.2.5 and included **spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar**
But now how to implement csrf token and how to configure it.
I refereed to [this](https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection/) blog but cant understand the configuration.

Comment: Then do the proper upgrade, you have old jars in your classpath leading to that issue. Make sure al your jars are 3.2.16 and not from older versions. The stacktrce/error indicates you are mixing versions.

Comment: Also not sure why you would need an upgrade, as you would only need Spring Security...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSRF protection was [introduced in Spring Security 3.2](https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection/). According maven, Spring Security 3.2 has a [dependency on `spring-core-3.2.6-RELEASE`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/3.2.0.RELEASE), so I would say no. You will have to upgrade the version of spring.

Comment: I Upgraded Spring to 3.2.5, Now how to implement AntiCSFRToken using it.

Comment: I also included spring-security-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar in my project. Now how to write spring security configuration.